# Using convolution layer trained weights for different image size

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to use the first three convolution layers of vgg-16 to generate feature maps.
But i want to use it with variable image size,i.e not imagenet size of 224x224 or 256x256. Such as 480x640or any other randome image dimension.

As convolution layer are independent of image spatial size, how can I use the weights for varying image sizes?
So how do we use the pre-trained weights of vgg-16 upto the first three convolution layers.
Kindly let me know if that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`As convolution layer are independent of image size`

Actually it's more complicated than that. The kernel itself is independent of the image size because we apply it on each pixel. And indeed, the training of these kernels can be reused.

But this means that the output size is dependent on the image size, because this is the number of nodes that are fed out of the layer for each input pixel. So the dense layer is not adapted to your image, even if the feature extractors are independent.

So you need to preprocess your image to fit into the size of the first layer or you retrain your dense layers from scratch.

When people talk about "transfer-learning" is what people have done in segmentation for decades. You reuse the best feature extractors and then you train a dedicated model with these features.

Comment: but when I was referring Stanford course on convolution it mentioned(http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/) -"However, some changes are straight-forward: Due to parameter sharing, you can easily run a pretrained network on images of different spatial size. This is clearly evident in the case of Conv/Pool layers because their forward function is independent of the input volume spatial size (as long as the strides “fit”). "  . Also as i am not verying or altering filter size and just using different image size , it should give me feature maps from 3rd conv layer

Comment: I basically want to train a new network which takes feature maps from the pre-trained vgg-16 with size different than the one it was trained on,vgg-16 is trained on 256x256, i want to use 480x640. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Reuse the CNN layers, but retrain the dense layers from scratch. Only option if you want to reuse their feature extractors.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to reuse variables of Convolution layer. First, you define a graph containing convolution layer, then you restore values of them. The following is a pseudo code

```
def network(your_inputs):
    filter1 = tf.get_variable(shape=[filter_size, filter_size, in_channel, out_channel], name="vgg16/layer1")
    features = tf.nn.conv2d(your_inputs, filter1, strides=[1,1,1,1])
    filter2 = tf.get_variable(shape=[filter_size, filter_size, in_channel, out_channel], name="vgg16/layer2")
    features = tf.nn.conv2d(features, filter2, strides=[1,1,1,1])

    restore_filters = [filter1, filter2]

    ...

    return logits, restore_filters 

outputs, restore_filters = network(inputs)
saver = tf.train.Saver(restore_filters)
saver.restore(sess, "vgg-checkpoint.ckpt")
```

Of course, you must match your filter sizes with VGG network. When you variable names differ from them of a checkpoint file, you can use Saver with dictionary argument.

Comment: will i be able to use a image of say 720p resolution for inference, eventhough network was trained for a smaller size? i intend to use a network with only conv layers. so that my final network can be used with different image sizes for inference